# Node js with socket io application

Tags: javascript, node.js, apache, socket.io, virtualhost

I have included the following lines in `.htaccess`:

```
#Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"#
```

I am able to run the node js with socket io application on http://www.example.com but when I try to run on https://www.example.com 
I am getting an error as `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header is present on the requested resource`. I tried creating a virtual host on CentOS, hosting on Apache web server in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/httpd.conf`. When I open a non-standard port like 3000 and listen on it, I get an error while running "port already in use". What should I do?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

You should implement cors on you're node express server !

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Or u can try to implement package for that https://github.com/agrueneberg/Corser